# Differentiable topk masking in pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, math, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to create a binary mask with zeros in the location with top `k` elements of the inputs and 1 everywhere else. Is there a differentiable way to achieve this in pytorch?

`k` is a fixed number

E.g. `input = torch.randn(3, 2, requires_grad=True)`

```
tensor([[ 1.7190, -0.8555],
        [ 1.9104, -1.1533],
        [-2.5418, -1.2975]], requires_grad=True)
```

`top_k_values, _ = torch.topk(input, 2) #say k=1`

```
tensor([[ 1.7190],
        [ 1.9104],
        [-1.2975]], grad_fn=<TopkBackward0>)
```

How do I use `top_k_values` or any other way to generate this mask in a differentiable manner

```
tensor([[0, 1]
         [0, 1]
         [1, 0], grad_fn= <....>)
```